# Is it possible to create a variable in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

Can i create a variable in PIG and concatenate them where on if the variable is dynamic- like current time?

I need a file name to be created based on the current time.

> %declare FILE_PREFIX file;
>
> %declare FILE_POSTFIX `date +%Y-%m-%d-%s`;

Can i do something like:

> file_name = '$FILE_PREFIX$FILE_POSTFIX';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
As of my Experience,I worked like below..
Passed parameter from command line to pig script filename and date..

pig  -f  myscript.pig --param file="india_" --param nw=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%s")  

In the pig script.


%declare FILE_PREFIX '$file$nw ';

A = load '/user/root/$FILE_PREFIX'   USING PigStorage(',') as (id1, name1);

dump A;
```